# Raytracing shadow/shading artifacts

Tags: shadow, raytracing

I am trying to write raytracer but actually I have some problem.

I have data structure for smooth triangle mesh and there is problem with shadow/shading (images)

http://ubuntuone.com/5PzgIFMPofsUfSusGE25jt

and

http://ubuntuone.com/0M37JviVUKiwu5b5iBhFKS

I know where is the problem. By interpolated normal is part of triangle "on light" but for shadow ray is triangle flat and it is in shadow.

Question is, how I can remove this artifact.
Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known artifact.  You can see [this page](http://wiki.povray.org/content/Knowledgebase%3aThe_Shadow_Line_Artifact) for a complete description as it relates to POV-Ray.

One potential solution, as mentioned there, is to have that object not cast any shadows. If it is part of a larger scene, perhaps have it cast shadows on other objects, but not on itself.

That page suggests a more complicated general algorithm as well, in the last section.